# Soundcloud limit access api

Tags: soundcloud

I am building an app about joke telling using soundcloud api. So does soundcloud limit 15000 applied in 24 hour means all my app in in every device can applied for 15000 or one app in individual  device?

Answer (score 0):

Form Sound cloud developers portal

> Effective July 1, all requests that result in access to a playable
> stream are subject to a limit of 15,000 requests per any 24-hour time
> window. Currently, this is inclusive of all requests that are made to
> /tracks/:id/stream.
>
> After a previous time window has expired, a new time window starts
> from the first request made.
>
> The majority of SoundCloud API rate limits are in the form of 24-hour
> time windows.

For more details visit
https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/rate-limits

Comment: Milap kundalia, you know it would be nice to inform user